# Assign null to interface in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

i have a interface in angular4

```
interface StatusDetail {
    statusName: string,
    name: string
}
```

and i have assigned some values to it like

//angular Component

```
     export class EditComponent implements OnInit{
         statusDetail: StatusDetail;
         ngOnInit() {
           this.statusDetail.statusName = 'text Status';
           this.statusDetail.name= 'text Name';
         }
     }
```

i'm trying to reset to default null like this

```
         SetNull() { 
           this.statusDetail = null
         }
```

but it gives error

> Type null is not assignable to type StatusDetail

how can i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to declare `statusDetail` as `StatusDetail | null`:

```
export class EditComponent implements OnInit{
     statusDetail: StatusDetail | null;
     ngOnInit() {
       this.statusDetail.statusName = 'text Status';
       this.statusDetail.name= 'text Name';
     }
 }
```

Comment: What's the point of having the interface then? Would it not make more sense to define a default StatusDetail with empty fields?

Comment: i can,t do this because every time i tried to access its values it give error of being null value

Comment: @bugs: I agree, this would be better.

Comment: @Faisal: Well, that's the nature of null. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here? Why are you setting it to null? Also, see bugs comment.

Comment: i have a condition on html <div statusDetail != null">Status is Not Null</div> i want to hide this via this condition

Comment: So, in that case you need to check for null wherever you want to use `statusDetail`. Or you can add a boolean as the condition: `hasStatusDetail: boolean;` and set this to true or false and use it in the HTML

Comment: i did it as this way no other option i found

Answer (score 4):

You can reset/initiate your interface like below.

```
this.statusDetail = <StatusDetail>{};
```

Now the object will have the default value. You can set to undefined too, why null btw ? Why not

```
this.statusDetail = undefined ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you defined the interface with those properties, it does not make too much sense to assign `null` to your object.

If you are trying to reset your default values, why don't you set them as empty?

```
SetNull() { 
  this.statusDetail = {
    statusName: '',
    name: ''
  }
}
```

---

If you want to check this condition in the HTML, you can create a new private method specifically for that:

```
isStatusDetailDefined(): boolean {
  return this.statusDetail.statusName && this.statusDetail.name
}
```

and

`*ngIf="isStatusDetailDefined()"`

Comment: but this condition will never get false ngIf !="statusDetail != null"

Comment: Because the condition doesn't make sense, given the interface. See the modified answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set null to interface value, you set `{} as any`

```
setNull(){
 this.statusDetail= {} as any
}
```